# How to get Custom Image Attribute in Block in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, product, custom, image

I created a custom image attribute in admin panel (image_big) to show a specific image as a background in single product page, but I am not being able to fetch it inside the Block Class or phtml file.

Block:

```
<?php
    namespace MyVendor\ImageBig\Block;

    class ProductBigImage extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView
    {
    }
```

Template:

```
<?php
// $product = $block->getProduct()->getId(); // this works I get the correct ProductID
$product = $block->getProduct();
$productImageAttr = $product->getCustomAttribute( 'image_big' );
$productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
    ->init($product, 'image_big')
    ->setImageFile($productImageAttr->getValue());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: NVM. Solved, I had to fetch it with ->getUrl()

Comment: Please Put it as answer,So in future other people will get help from your